# Show that the two given sets have equal cardinality by describing a bijection

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, cardinals

Show that the two given sets have equal cardinality by describing a bijection from
one to the other. Describe your bijection with a formula (i.e. not as a table)

My two sets are:  (The set of all integers) and set S = {x ∈ (the set of all real numbers) : sin(x) = 1}

I know I need to make sure it is both injective and surjective, and find some f -> S defined by (some function, I suspect the answer is f(n) = (2*pi)(n) - (3pi/2) because the set of all real numbers where sin(x) =1, are all 2pi multiples of pi/2.  i.e., pi/2, (2pi)(pi/2), (4pi)(pi/2), etc.)

Past that, I'm unsure on how I can prove these sets are equal in cardinality with a bijection.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> because the set of all real numbers where sin(x) =1, are all 2pi multiples of pi/2. i.e., pi/2, (2pi)(pi/2), (4pi)(pi/2), etc.)

**Wrong**.

$2\pi\cdot \frac\pi2=\pi$, and $\sin(\pi)=0\neq 1$. You are rushing, and in rushing you are making silly mistakes. That's never a good idea in mathematics. Slow down and re-think what you wrote, you aren't that far from the answer. Only then, read the second part of my answer.

---

Your general idea is correct. You can write $S$ as

$$\{\text{Some expression involving $k$}| k\in\mathbb Z\}$$

and that expression naturally induces a bijection between $A$ and $S$.

Comment: ok,  so now I have f (n) = pi/2 + n (2pi) which works as a function from my tests. (n =1, 2, 3, etc) from this, i was able to work out f (m) = f (n) => m = n.  Does this imply bijection?

Comment: @ViciousCritter What you wrote only implies injection. You still need to prove surjectivity (but you're almost there!)